# Using jQuery to select span elements and the text following them

Tags: jquery

I am trying to parse data from a website by using jquery to select the relevant information. But one section is a bit annoying. It has a variety of fields like color, weight, height. Most of the time, it is the same, but not always. So I would like to parse it. I would like to select each field, see that the first is color, and then be able to save the value "black" in my predefined color variable.

But I don't know a way to select each span element and the text following it. Is there a sensible way to parse this data?

```
<span class="outer">
  <b>Samsonite</b>
  <br>
  <br>
  <span class="inner">Color</span>
  black
  <br>
  <span class="inner">Weight</span>
  5 kg
  <br>
  <span class="inner">Height</span>
  50 cm
  <br>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var i = 0;
$('.outer span.inner').each(function(i, obj) {
    if($obj.text() =="Color"){
      $color_index  = i;
    }
});

$element = $(".outer span.inner");
$element = $element.find('span').remove();
$text = $(".outer span.inner").html().split("<br>")[parseInt(i) + 3];
```

Comment: Thanks. This really helped.